# Why ios barcode scanner using cordova is slow compared with android devices?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Hi I'm developing a cross platform mobile application using `cordova`. Now I'm try to do barcode scanner and `QR` code scanner using   [cordova barcode plugin](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner) It works fine for me but is very slow when compared to android mobile phones.

And also I refer some website in that only in phone 4 is not working and I wont refocus. But I don't know what is the problem. Can some one please help me for this. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you comparing the performance of a html-based app with a native app?

Comment: yes using cordova i build app for both andriod and ios. Andriod mobile scans the barcode faster but iphone takes more time @Nanoc